# Can't find the relation beatween these numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, relations, correlation, function-and-relation-composition

Good morning, I am developing a web app on Body Mass Index calculation. Related to the BMI calculation I want to show a counter. Inside the counter, that looks like a speedometer, there's an arrow that rotates and points to the BMI result. Like that:

[Here you can find the graphic reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDaT7.png)

The rotation of the arrow is determined by a number, that changes when the BMI changes. I can actually see the results but I can't find the formula behind the releation beatween the BMI and this number. This is the chart I have extracted:

```
+------+--------+
| BMI  | NUMBER |
+------+--------+
|  19  |   36   |
| 19.1 |  36.6  |
| 19.2 |  37.2  |
| 19.3 |  37.8  |
+---------------+
```

Considerations:

When BMI rises by 0.1, the number rises by 0.6 . I need to know, for example: given BMI 21, what equals the "number"?

Additional info:
BMI formula is: `weight (kg) / (height*height) (m²)`

Maybe it is easy, but I am not good at math.

Comment: Number = BMI times 6 minus 78. The method was to set Number = BMI times a plus b and solve for (a,b) the four (redundant) equations given by your chart. The solution is a=6, b=-78.

Comment: Thank you, Anne